# PHP: How to check if post when normal link

Tags: php

I have this

```
          <form action="profiles.php" method="POST" name="SearchAdvanced" id="SearchAdvanced">
            <a style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;" id="submitSearchAdvanced">Sök </a>
            <script>
                        $('#submitSearchAdvanced').click(function() { 
    javascript:document.SearchAdvanced.submit();
        });
            </script>
</form>
```

How should i call it? should i do if($_POST["SearchAdvanced"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, which will be `"GET"` or `"POST"`.

The [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for `$_SERVER` describes the indices in detail.

Comment: Cant i just call the submit "link" somehow, like you can with the button

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking request method, you can also do a check for variable being set in POST:

```
isset($_POST['SearchAdvanced'])
```

Offtopic:
Also, "pro" tip: never uset double quotes ( " ) if you do not have variable definition in it.. There is a difference between single and double quotes in PHP. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

If what you posted is the entire form, you don't need to submit it using POST, because you are not altering a resource on the server. Instead, you should remove the form and leave only the link - and maybe style it using CSS like you did.